# How to calculate 1 share movement

Tags: stocks, options

I'm trying to figure out how much the price of a stock will change if a particular amount of shares are sold at that time.

"X stock" is at $100 per share. If I sell 1 share how much will that affect the $100 price?

Comment: If it is a liquid stock you will not change the price at all by selling 1 share.

Answer (score 4):

The price of a share has two components:

Bid: The highest price that someone who wants to buy shares is willing to pay for them.

Ask: The lowest price that someone who has a share is willing to sell it for.

The ask is always higher than the bid, since if they were equal the buyer and seller would have a deal, make a transaction, and that repeats until they are not equal. For stock with high volume, there is usually a very small difference between the bid and ask, but a stock with lower volume could have a major difference.

When you say that the share price is $100, that could mean different things. You could be talking about the price that the shares sold for in the most recent transaction (and that might not even be between the current bid and ask), or you could be talking about any of the bid, the ask, or some value in between them. If you have shares that you are interested in selling, then the bid is what you could immediately sell a share for.

If you sell a share for $100, that means someone was willing to pay you $100 for it. If after buying it, they still want to buy more for $100 each, or someone else does, then the bid is still $100, and you haven't changed the price.

If no one else is willing to pay more than $90 for a share, then the price would drop to $90 next time a transaction takes place and thats what you would be able to immediately sell the next share for.

Comment: Does that mean that  two seperate people selling off 2 different amounts of shares at the same price have the same effect ??? Quantity doesn't matter ?

Comment: @theloosegoos Quantity does matter. If someone wanted to sell 1,000,000 shares of "stock X" for $100 then they would have to find enough people willing to buy that stock for $100. If there were only 100,000 people who wanted to but stock X for $100, then that person would have to reduce the price to sell all the stock.

Comment: +1 for your explanation of why the bid and ask prices are always different.

Comment: @theloosegoos What Daniel said. Quantity matters. If there are three people A,B, and C who each want to buy 1000 shares and A is willing to pay $80 per share, B is willing to pay $90 and C is willing to pay $100. If you decide to sell 1000 shares or less, at market price, then you will sell them all to C for $100 each. If you decide to sell 3000 shares, you will only be able to sell 1000 to C, so the next 1000 will be sold to B for $90 each, and the next 1000 will be sold to A for $80 for each.

Answer (score 1):

Unless other people believe you have a *reason* for selling at a lower price, your sale probably has no lasting effect at all on the market. Of course, if people see you dump a few million dollars' worth of shares at a discount, they may be inclined to believe you have a reason. But if you just sell a few, they will conclude the reason is just that you needed cash in a hurry.

Comment: I recently came across a person that said  " if you sell say one whole bitcoin that will move price around 10 cents. I was curious to if this was true for one and second. How would you know that

Comment: Bitcoins are a different question, which I won't touch... But I have no idea what that statement might be based on.

Comment: @theloosegoos That might be true at some particular exchange with very high spreads and very poor liquidity. But right now, just on Bitstamp alone you'd have to sell 18 bitcoins to move the price 10 cents, and it would likely just snap right back.

Comment: Now I'm trying to get the formula or atleast a resource to make that calculation myself.

Comment: Good luck. I do not believe any such formula exists.

Comment: Then how do exchanges do it. How do the people above make those accusations.

Comment: Exchanges don't set prices. They just provide a place for buyers and sellers to meet. It's up to those individuals to decide what prices they are willing to pay and accept. Unless your transaction changes how other people are making that decision, it has no lasting effect on price. I believe everyone above has said that, in different words.

Comment: @theloosegoos With data.

Comment: I'm still battling a lot of pre-conceived notions this is the reason I'm struggling. Too much conflicted info. But I'm coming to the conclusion that the price swing due to share sell off is dynamic.

Comment: @theloosegoos They are dynamic, that's correct. As an example with bitcoin, take a look at this [exchange's order book](https://www.quadrigacx.com/trade/btc/usd). You'll see buy orders and sell orders. The top buy order is the current bid, the top sell order (lowest price) is the current ask). If you have 1 bitcoin to sell, and the top buy order is for more than 1 bitcoin, you won't affect the price at all. If you have 100 bitcoins to sell, you would work your way through that whole buy order list, selling to buyers who aren't willing to pay quite as much as the first buyer.

Comment: Ok so here is the skinny!!!! There is a popular web page called  cryptowat.ch. On this page if you hover over DOM graph it tell you how much bit coin you need to buy or sell to move the market a specific percent.     How can he do that

Comment: @theloosegoos Use and @ like I did to notify people if you want them to see your comment. That page is using API's to pull the order books from various exchanges. It's not doing a calculation, it's looking at how many people are currently looking to buy/sell bitcoin, and at what prices they are willing to sell them at. The resulting number is how much you would affect the price if you sold that many all at once at market price. It means that you would sell to all the buyers who currently have orders to buy above that price.

Comment: The price would quickly/instantly correct as other buyers (including bots) show up looking to take advantage of any arbitrage if there is any, until their isn't. A savy seller wouldn't sell with a market order at that particular moment on that exchange.

Comment: @Paulpro (conforming) Yes this is exactly what my post is about I should have mentioned that web page earlier. I'm currently trying to figure out how he made that calculation. Regardless if it will spring back I'm still interested in how he made the calculation.

Comment: @theloosegoos It's not a calculation. It's just the number of bitcoins that currently have buyers waiting to buy them above that price.

Comment: @theloosegoos: If crypto watch is claiming to be able to tell you this, they're running a scam. Or they too are very, very confused.

Comment: I wish I could post a picture but the points system is preventing me. After the page Initially loads click the btcusd graph it loads candle stick then on the right there is arrow tabs under the first collapsible window on the very right there is a DOM graph hover over the domain graph or touch with touch screen and it will literally say. How much bitcoin you need to buy before moving the price x amount and it will cost you x amount

Comment: @theloosegoos: I don't think a picture would help. I believe you when you say they are making that claim; I don't believe them.

Comment: Which is why I'm so interested in how this is done because I would then deduce they have gaps and holes in all the data.

Comment: @theloosegoos: Ask them. I believe the answer is that it isn't done.